# dplyr `nth()` can't get it to pipe [Error in length(n) == 1]

Tags: r, dplyr

I can extract a value from the mtcars data frame using dplyr's `nth()` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
nth(mtcars$cyl, 2)
#> [1] 6
```

However, when I pipe it I get the following error.

```
mtcars %>% nth(cyl, 2)
#> Error in length(n) == 1 : object 'cyl' not found

mtcars %>% nth(.$cyl, 2)
#> Error in nth(., .$cyl, 2) : length(n) == 1 is not TRUE
```

How do I properly 'pipe' this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?nth`

> x - A vector

when you do `mtcars$cyl` it returns a vector. However,

```
mtcars %>% nth(cyl, 2)
```

is passing a column `cyl`.

you might need to `pull` first to get a vector.

```
mtcars %>% pull(cyl) %>% nth(2)
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The first argument of nth is not the data frame so use brace brackets and refer to dot explicitly:

```
mtcars %>% { nth(.$cyl, 2) }
## [1] 6
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use magrittr's `%$%` operator:

```
library(magrittr)

mtcars %$% nth(cyl, 2)
## [1] 6
```

**3)** or use `with`:

```
mtcars %>% with(nth(cyl, 2))
## [1] 6
```

**4)** or use `$` like this:

```
mtcars %>% `$`(cyl) %>% nth(2)
## [1] 6
```

**5)** or magrittr `extract2`:

```
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>% extract2("cyl") %>% nth(2)
## [1] 6
```